# My circular Linked List is not Displaying the last node

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Here is the code to display the single circular linked list that I have created. The program takes the value but displays the inserted the inserted values till second last node from the head. 
The code for insertion is as follows-

```
if(head==NULL)
{
    new_node=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    printf("Enter the data : ");
    scanf("%d",&new_node->data);
    new_node->next=NULL;
    head=new_node;
    link=head;
    head->next=head;
}
else
{
    new_node=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    printf("Enter the data : ");
    scanf("%d",&new_node->data);
    new_node->next=head;
    link->next=new_node;
    link=new_node;
}
void display()
{
    struct list *link;
    link=head;
    while(link->next!=head)
    {
        printf("%d\t",link->data);
        link=link->next;
    }
```

Comment: Does a circular linked list have a last node?

Comment: Check my edited answer. It works perfectly

Comment: @EdHeal by last node i mean the last value that I have inserted into the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as follows

```
while(link->next!=head){
    printf("%d\t",link->data);
    link=link->next;
}
if(link != null){ //To check weather the link is empty and to print the last node
    printf("%d\t",link->data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! will use the second option.

Comment: This will not work, because in the first iteration `head==link`. Then you print nothing

Comment: @PhilFighter Yes it has an issue but the first code will work

Comment: @PriyanshSrivastava use the first option. It will work without any error

Comment: 'void display(){
 struct list *link;
 link=head;
 while(link->next!=head){
  printf("%d\t",link->data);
  link=link->next;}
 printf("%d\t",link->data);}'

Comment: @PriyanshSrivastava If you print without checking that if condition. If the link is empty it will shows an error. If this answer worked for you. Mark this answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

```
link = head;
do {
    printf("%d\t",link->data);
    link=link->next;
} while(link!=head);
```